# Laravel loop filters uuid characters

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to display uuid of an item in my views but it output is different from the actual data.

```
@forelse($sections as $section)
 <tr>
     <th scope="row">{{ $loop->iteration }}</th>
         <td>{{ $section->title_hy }}</td>
         <td>{{ $section->title_en }}</td>
          <td><div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2">
          <i class="fas fa-edit mr-2"></i>@lang('sections.edit')</a>
          <form class="contain-button-sm" action="{{ route('sections.destroy', $section->id) }}" method="post">
          @method('delete')
          @csrf
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
          <i class="fas fa-trash mr-2"></i>@lang('sections.delete')</button>
          </form>
       </div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Where the output for $section-> id is

```
22
```

When in reality it should be

```
"22f3ffe3-855a-4f27-90c9-0f40894887be"
```

I even dumped the sections and this is what's inside

```
Collection {#291 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▶
    0 => Section {#292 ▶
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "sections"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:5 [▶
        "id" => "22f3ffe3-855a-4f27-90c9-0f40894887be"
        "title_hy" => "Արվեստ"
        "title_en" => "Art"
        "created_at" => "2019-08-07 21:03:35"
        "updated_at" => "2019-08-07 21:03:35"
      ]
      #original: array:5 [▶
        "id" => "22f3ffe3-855a-4f27-90c9-0f40894887be"
        "title_hy" => "Արվեստ"
        "title_en" => "Art"
        "created_at" => "2019-08-07 21:03:35"
        "updated_at" => "2019-08-07 21:03:35"
      ]
      #changes: []
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶
        0 => "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When i dump single section from loop it filters the characters and only leaves the first two numbers for some reason. Is there a way for me to get the full id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to casting the **id** column to **string** in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'id' => 'string'
]
```

By default the **id** is **integer**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$section['id']
```

or this

```
$section['_id']
```

and try passing the {id} in your route URL. For example:

```
Route::delete('{id}', 'ProjectController@destroy')->middleware('verified');
```

Comment: Same thing unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. The only thing that helps is getting the table through the DB facade instead of getting the model through Eloquent. DB:table('my_table')->get() instead of Model::get(). Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at the model, also look at the answer above, it might help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32246274)

Comment: In my situation, it was not possible to change something in the model. If you check then make sure getting the model through the DB facade disables the unwanted behavior.